# Javascript stream parse xml

Tags: javascript, xml, charts, google-visualization, large-files

I have several xml files I would like to filter through in Javascript to populate a google charts scatter graph.

The problem is, I have to use stream parsing as each file is very large, upwards of 3.5 MB.

*How do I pass data from a 4MB xml file into a javascript array I can loop through without running out of memory*

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootNode a="1">
    <parentNode b="2" c="3" d="4">
        <childNode e="5" f="7" g="7"/>
        <childNode e="2" f="9" g="4"/>
        <childNode e="11" f="7" g="3"/>
        ...
    </parentNode>
</rootNode>
```

To

```
var chart = [],
fIsSeven = [],
childNode = /*Each node of xml*/;

// Filter results and save data to 2D array
foreach (childNode) {
    if(f == 7) {
        fIsSeven = [e, g];
        chart.push(fIsSeven);
    }
}

...

// Use array to populate google chart
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['e', 'g'],

        forEach (chart) {
            [e, g]
        }
    ]);

...

}
```

Comment: _"Google is returning a lot of results I don't understand"_ Not sure what issue is?

Comment: could you post your results as well?

Comment: the fastest way i found to load a google data table from a large xml file is to use xsl to transform the data into [google's json format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), then create the data table directly from the json -- have an example at work i can share tomorrow if needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fastest way i found to load a google data table from a large xml file is to use xsl to transform the data into [google's json format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), then create the data table directly from the json...

---

following is a sample of XML data from a cognos report used to load google...

**XML**

```
<metadata>
      <item name="Level 1" type="xs:string" length="38"/>
      <item name="Level 2" type="xs:string" length="302"/>
      <item name="Level 3" type="xs:string" length="302"/>
      <item name="Level 4" type="xs:string" length="302"/>
      <item name="Level 5" type="xs:string" length="302"/>
      <item name="Expenditure Group" type="xs:string" length="48"/>
      <item name="GL Number" type="xs:double" precision="2"/>
      <item name="Actual" type="xs:double" precision="2"/>
      <item name="Budget" type="xs:double" precision="2"/>
      <item name="Forecast" type="xs:double" precision="2"/>
      <item name="Category" type="xs:string" length="102"/>
</metadata>
<data>
    <row>
        <value>SBU</value>
        <value>BU</value>
        <value>Department</value>
        <value>Office</value>
        <value>Site</value>
        <value>Expense</value>
        <value>3</value>
        <value>13811.22</value>
        <value>6175</value>
        <value>13811.22</value>
        <value>Category</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>SBU</value>
        <value>BU</value>
        <value>Department</value>
        <value>Office</value>
        <value>Site</value>
        <value>Expense</value>
        <value>3</value>
        <value>13811.22</value>
        <value>6175</value>
        <value>13811.22</value>
        <value>Category</value>
    </row>
    ...
```

---

following is the XSL used to transform the XML to google's JSON format...

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:cog="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    {
      "cols": [
        {"label": "SBU", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "BU", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "Department", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "Office", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "Site", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "Expenditure Group", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "Period", "type": "number", "p": {"format": "d2"}},
        {"label": "Actual", "type": "number", "p": {"format": "n2"}},
        {"label": "Budget", "type": "number", "p": {"format": "n2"}},
        {"label": "Forecast", "type": "number", "p": {"format": "n2"}},
        {"label": "O&amp;M Category", "type": "string"}
      ],
      "rows": [
      <xsl:for-each select="//cog:row">
        {"c":[
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[1]" />"},
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[2]" />"},
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[3]" />"},
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[4]" />"},
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[5]" />"},
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[6]" />"},
          {"v": <xsl:value-of select="cog:value[7]" />},
          {"v": <xsl:value-of select="cog:value[8]" />},
          {"v": <xsl:value-of select="cog:value[9]" />},
          {"v": <xsl:value-of select="cog:value[10]" />},
          {"v": "<xsl:value-of select="cog:value[11]" />"}
        ]}<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      ]
    }
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

following is a snippet of the JavaScript to perform the transformation...

**JavaScript**

```
// create xsl processor
var xslProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xslProcessor.importStylesheet(sender.target.responseXML);  // responseXML = result from loading xsl file above

// perform transformation
var jsonData = xslProcessor.transformToFragment(sender.get_xml(), document).textContent;  // get_xml() = result from loading xml file above

// load google data table
dataTableSummary = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

---

using this approach, in google chrome...

loading **3.1 MB** of XML data takes on average **1.1 seconds**

loading **3.6 MB** of XML data takes on average **1.4 seconds**

which includes time for loading the XML and XSL files via `XMLHttpRequest`

time taken to perform the transformation alone, 3.6 MB takes around 300 ms...

haven't encountered any issues with *running out of memory*...

Comment: I ended up going the JSON route my own way but honestly this answer looks like an even better solution

Comment: it works well, but trying to include logic in the xsl will slow it down -- typically build the data table, then use google's data view to filter, create custom columns, format values, etc...

Comment: if you need to support ie < edge for the xsl transformation -- i have that snippet as well...